# Build JSON string without repeating results in result set

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know how to stop repeating a common value when building a JSON string in TSQL.  I need the total count of the sub-select in the root of the JSON structure, and not repeated constantly inside the data section.  I don't know how to rearrange my SELECT statements to get the JSON string I want.

"recordsFiltered" represents a total number of records that were filtered & returned from a user-initiated search.  I only need this number one time in my JSON string.

Here is the DESIRED result:

```
    {
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 137920,
    "recordsFiltered": 55,
    "data": [
        {
            "DT_RowId": 1029833,
            "PositionTitle": "Total SQL Chad",
            "Department": "Nice Suburbs",
        },
        {
            "DT_RowId": 1029834,
            "PositionTitle": "Beta SQL Programmer",
            "Department": "Still Lives with Mom",
        },

    ...
    ]
}
```

As you can see, this is a pretty standard query, and its result below.  "recordsFiltered" repeats often.  That is undesirable.

```
--QUERY BASELINE
select
    count(RowID) over() as recordsFiltered
    ,RowID as DT_RowID
    ,LastName
    ,PositionTitle
from
    badges
where
    LastName = 'Dean'
for json path, root ('data'), include_null_values

--RESULT
{
    "data": [
    {
        "recordsFiltered": 55,
        "DT_RowID": 1005791,
        "LastName": "Dean",
        "PositionTitle": ""
    },
    {
        "recordsFiltered": 55,
        "DT_RowID": 1011253,
        "LastName": "Dean",
        "PositionTitle": "Instructional Assistant"
    },

    ...
    ]
}
```

Here is personal attempt number 187.  See that I try to get the count into a "higher" SELECT statement, but "recordsFiltered" is still part of the data section...  What do I need to do to stop or exclude the repeated entries in the final JSON string?  This is pretty close...

```
--ATTEMPT 187
select

    json_value(_.data, '$[0].recordsFiltered') as recordsFiltered
    ,_.data

from
    (
        select
            isnull((
                select
                    count(RowID) over() as recordsFiltered
                    ,RowID as DT_RowID
                    ,LastName
                    ,PositionTitle
                from
                    badges
                where
                    LastName = 'Dean'
                for json path, include_null_values
            ), '[]') as data

    ) _

for json path, include_null_values, without_array_wrapper

--RESULT
{
"recordsFiltered": "55",
"data": [
    {
        "recordsFiltered": 55,
        "DT_RowID": 1005791,
        "LastName": "Dean",
        "PositionTitle": ""
    },
    {
        "recordsFiltered": 55,
        "DT_RowID": 1011253,
        "LastName": "Dean",
        "PositionTitle": "Instructional Assistant"
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

============sample data/table============

It's a simple "flat" table, I've exclude some of the columns for "privacy".

```
create table [dbo].[Badges](
[RowID] [int] identity(1000001,1) not null,
[LastName] [varchar](32) not null,
[PositionTitle] [varchar](64) not null,
)
```

Comment: Sample data of what your data looks like in your table will considerbly help us help you. The expected JSON result implies that there *should* be 2 tables involved, not 1.

Comment: 1 table, with 1 primary key,  RowID [int].  I will nail something up in just a moment...

Comment: @larnu I forgot to include my RowID in my question, which I've updated that, and I provided an idea of the Table design at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next query should satisfy your requirements.

1- Filter the records and save them to a temporary table.

2- Calculate the affected records.

3- Generate the json with the expected information.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#Filtered];

;WITH
[Filtered]
AS
(
    SELECT
         [RowID]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[PositionTitle]
        ,[Department]
    FROM [dbo].[Badges]
    WHERE ([LastName] = 'Dean')
)
SELECT
    *
INTO [#Filtered]
FROM [Filtered];

DECLARE @RecordsFiltered INT = @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT
     [draw] = 1
    ,[recordsTotal] = COUNT(1)
    ,[recordsFiltered] = @RecordsFiltered
    ,[data] =
    (
        SELECT
             [DT_RowId] = [F].[RowID]
            ,[F].[PositionTitle]
            ,[F].[Department]
        FROM [#Filtered] AS [F]
        FOR JSON PATH
    )
FROM [dbo].[Badges] AS [B]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

-- Here another version without use temporary tables

```
;WITH
[Filtered]
AS
(
    SELECT
         [RowID]
        ,[LastName]
        ,[PositionTitle]
        ,[Department]
    FROM [dbo].[Badges]
    WHERE ([LastName] = 'Dean')
)
SELECT
     [draw] = 1
    ,[recordsTotal] = COUNT(1)
    ,[recordsFiltered] = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Filtered])
    ,[data] =
    (
        SELECT
             [DT_RowId] = [F].[RowID]
            ,[F].[PositionTitle]
            ,[F].[Department]
        FROM [Filtered] AS [F]
        FOR JSON PATH
    )
FROM [dbo].[Badges] AS [B]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Comment: I will explore this.  My boss doesn't want me to use #temp tables, he told me to use @ table vars.  HOWEVER, I noticed in my particular scenario, the #temp table was way faster than the @ temp var.  So, I was trying to do this all through a SELECT.... But give me a few moments to explore your idea.

Comment: I updated the answer with a version without use temporary table.

Comment: CTE's, baby.  OKAY, is this what you did:  1) declare a CTE, 2) do your WHERE stuff inside the CTE, finally 3) do a select on the CTE to generate the JSON ??

Comment: @raydlevel5 Correct, I have declared the CTE not to repeat the query to calculate the recordsFiltered field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the next approach may help:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Badges (
   [RowID] [int] identity(1000001,1) not null,
   [LastName] [varchar](32) not null,
   [PositionTitle] [varchar](64) not null,
)
INSERT INTO Badges
   ([LastName], [PositionTitle])
VALUES
   ('Dean', 'Instructional Assistant'),
   ('Dean', 'Instructional Assistant'),
   ('Luke', 'Instructional Assistant')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   Draw = 1,
   recordsTotals = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Badges),
   recordsFiltered = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Badges WHERE LastName = 'Dean'),
   Data = (
      SELECT RowID, LastName, PositionTitle
      FROM Badges
      WHERE LastName = 'Dean'
      FOR JSON AUTO
   )
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```
{
   "Draw":1,
   "recordsTotal":3,
   "recordsFiltered":2,
   "Data":[
      {
         "RowID":1000001,
         "LastName":"Dean",
         "PositionTitle":"Instructional Assistant"
      },
      {
         "RowID":1000002,
         "LastName":"Dean",
         "PositionTitle":"Instructional Assistant"
      }
   ]
}
```

Notes:

You need to check the performance of this statement.

Comment: OKAY, this looks really clean, but the the "recordsFiltered" is not the total of the entire table, but the count of the filtered results.  Basically, "the total count of the results in the sub-select".

Comment: @raydlevel5 Just place a `WHERE` clause where it's needed - in the `COUNT` part or in the `FOR JSON AUTO` part. I've updated the answer. Thanks.